# Better way to display date of birth

Tags: java, date

I know this is the simplest way to display date of birth, is there a better way or a more professional way to display my date of birth? or a java util tool that I can use? This is so far the only way I know how to display my date of birth.

```
 class dateofbirth
    {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        
        public int getDay()
        {
            return day;
        }
        public void setDay(int day)
        {
            this.day=day;
        }
        public int getMonth()
        {
            return month;
        }
        public void setMonth(int month)
        {
            this.month=month;
        }
        public int getYear()
        {
            return year;
        }
        public void setYear(int year)
        {
            this.year=year;
        }
        public void displayInfo()
        {
            System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",day,month,year);
        }
    }
    class Tutorial
    {
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            dateofbirth dob=new dateofbirth();
            
            dob.setDay(9);
            dob.setMonth(9);
            dob.setYear(1996);
            dob.displayInfo();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: As an aside, I don’t think you want to set year, month and day of month independently. I never heard about anyone changing the month they were born while keeping year and day of month the same. Provide a setter that sets all three instead. For example accepting a `LocalDate` as argument.

Comment: Besides, you have nowhere any validation. If I say I was born on the 63rd day of the minus 15th month of 1970, would you believe me?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) of `java.time` to store Date of Birth

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(1996, 9, 9);
```

Then you can use `DateTimeFormatter` to format your date also by specifying the pattern

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dateOfBirth.format(formatter));
```

Output: `1996-09-09`

Comment: How do you create a method to store, LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(....)

Comment: Do you want to store a field of LocalDate inside your class? If yes you can pass the LocalDate in the constructor or create inside your constructor with data.

Comment: How about displaying my date of birth, example: 8 August, 1996. Is it possible? Sorry new to Java

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the pattern you want like for your example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM, uuuu")`. You can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for details about _Patterns for Formatting and Parsing_

Comment: `8 September,1996` is not the way to specify the pattern you need to use you need use `d MMMM, uuuu` here `d` for date `MMMM` for full month string and `uuuu` for years. You will find details in link of my prev comment.

Comment: Oh wow! great, Thanks for helping me to solve it. I have so much more questions I need to ask, is there a way for you to help me?

Comment: You can ask in SO in a new question, then it will help others who have the same question in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222486/discussion-between-eklavya-and-cruz-ng).